# Sage pay error 3069 on Adobe commerce cloud

Tags: magento2, opayo

We have a Adobe commerce cloud environment where we have integrated sagepay. I have whitelisted all the domain IP in sagepay portal but still I get and error states

> 3079 : The ClientIPAddress format is invalid. Should not include leading zero's, and only include values in the range of 0 to 255.

Can anyone help me to resolve or debug this issue?

I was expecting to get payments page